# On navigating to next page, crystal report asks for logon info again

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

[image: NextPageButton]

1) When ever I click onto *Go to Next Page* my report gets post back and it again gets time to load.

2)The *Next Page* button works fine to navigate page 2 but when I am at page 2 and I press button to *Go to Next Page* It again loads the same page no. 2 but when I enter page number manually it gives me the correct page.

3) If I don't fire button event in PostBack it asks me for login credential.

How can I make my report performance more fast.

Code on PageLoad

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    mycode ....................
} else {
    ViewRpt_Click(ViewRpt, null);
}
```

My Button to view report

```
Protected Void ViewRpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ReportDocument report;
    if (Session["Report"] == null) {
        report = new ReportDocument();
        report.FileName = Server.MapPath("Report/myreport.rpt");
        Class1.setLogon(this.CrystalReportViewer1, report);
        report.Refresh();
        Session.Add("Report", report);
    }
    ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
    ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    paramField.Name = "@NEWUSER";
    paramDiscreteValue.Value = this.myuser.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Trim();
    paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
    paramFields.Add(paramField);

    CrystalReportViewer1.HasCrystalLogo = false;
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Session["Report"];
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    this.CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
}
```

If I don't fire the button event in post back it asks me to give login credential again and again.

Here is my login method

```
public static void setLogon(CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer c, ReportDocument crDoc) {
    ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    myConnectionInfo.ServerName = server;
    myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = db;
    myConnectionInfo.UserID = uid;
    myConnectionInfo.Password = pass;
    TableLogOnInfos crTableLogonInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    TableLogOnInfo crTableLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    Tables crTables = crDoc.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
    {
        crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo;
        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer to the answer in SO post: [Logon failed error when navigating to next page on Crystal Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33262971/5104101)