# Logon failed error when navigating to next page on Crystal Reports VS2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm developing a crystal report in Visual Studio 2008 that uses a couple of different databases as DataSource. Everything was working fine until I try to navigate to page 2. The code that works (because it has limited results) looks like this

```
Dim mssqlstr As String
mssqlstr = "SELECT TOP 1 t1.*, t2.column1, t2.column2 FROM 
        tablename1 As t1, tablename2 As t2 WHERE t1.ID = '" & txtID.Text & "'
        AND t2.column2 = RTRIM(LEFT(t1.column_2, 2)) ORDER BY t1.ID DESC"
Dim DAms As New OleDbDataAdapter(mssqlstr, conn)
DAms.Fill(dsQRpt, "tablename")

'The code below is shared by the other subreport functions
QPrpt.Load(Server.MapPath("crreport.rpt"))
QPrpt.SetDataSource(dsQRpt)
crQtrProgress.ReportSource = QPrpt
crQtrProgress.RefreshReport()
```

But when I need a larger result set from this query

```
mssqlstr = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM tablename ORDER BY ID DESC"
```

I get the error

> Logon failed.
>   Details: crdb_adoplus : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Error in File C:\Users\ALFRED~1.CAL\AppData\Local\Temp\rptQuarterlyProgress {10667888-35C5-41CA-93EF-214A64741965}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters."

Both queries use the same connection string and the report fields are coming from drag and dropped fields in a datasheet (.xsd)

I should also mention that the report is using multiple subreports with each subreport coming from a different DataSource. All the subreports are coded similarly and work fine except for when the results have to carry over to the next page. If I limit the number of results then the I get the desired results from each subreport but if the data carries over to another page...kaboom! I get the **"Unable to connect..."** error.

Also the DataSet connects to the database and displays the table data with no problem. I've been looking for a solution but not finding anything that matches my situation.

Thanks for any help offered

**SOLUTION**
Credit goes to **haraman** for providing the answer. Here's the working code

```
    Dim dsQRpt = New Data.DataSet
    Dim QPrpt = New ReportDocument

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load        

        If Page.IsPostBack Then
            If Session.Item("CRpt") IsNot Nothing Then
                QPrpt = Session.Item("CRpt")
            End If
            crQtrProgress.ReportSource = QPrpt
            crQtrProgress.RefreshReport()
        Else
            If Session.Item("CRpt") IsNot Nothing Then
               Session.Remove("CRpt")
            End If
            Session.Add("CRpt", QPrpt)
        End If

    End Sub

Protected Sub btRunReport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim mssqlstr As String    
        mssqlstr = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM tablename ORDER BY ID DESC"

        Dim DAms As New OleDbDataAdapter(mssqlstr, conn)    
        DAms.Fill(dsQRpt, "tablename")

        'Populate Report 
        QPrpt.Load(Server.MapPath("crreport.rpt"))            
        QPrpt.SetDataSource(dsQRpt)
        crQtrProgress.ReportSource = QPrpt

        Session.Add("CRpt", QPrpt) 

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you on WinForms application or WebForms? And which database?

Comment: This is a Web Application using a SQL Server database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems CrystalReportViewer loses the ReportDocument on PostBack. You can try saving the ReportDocument in a session and then on PostBack reassign it to the CrystalReportViewer on PageLoad event such as

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Me.Load

    QPrpt.Load(Server.MapPath("crreport.rpt"))
    QPrpt.SetDataSource(dsQRpt)

    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        If Session.Item("CRpt") IsNot Nothing Then
            QPrpt = Session.Item("CRpt")
        End If
    Else
        If Session.Item("CRpt") IsNot Nothing Then
            Session.Remove("CRpt")
        End If
        Session.Add("CRpt", QPrpt)
    End If
    crQtrProgress.ReportSource = QPrpt
    crQtrProgress.RefreshReport()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    If Session.Item("CRpt") IsNot Nothing Then
        Session.Remove("CRpt")
    End If
    Session.Add("CRpt", QPrpt)
End Sub
```

In case you have specific problem in setting LogOnInfo then you may also check this SO post [Report asking for database login on setting DataTable as DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33246823/5104101)

Comment: Dude, you rock! Had to make a few minor adjustments but this is just what I needed. I'll update my post with the working code. Thanks!