# Crystal Report Viewer is prompting the user for login credentials even though the reports data source is a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET web application with crystal report integration. In the code behind, I create my dataset and set the report document's datasource to the newly created dataset. The report intially loads the first page fine, but when a user pages to the next page of the report, they are prompted for login credentials.
[Here's the login prompt after trying to page to the next page in the report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwK8h.png)

If the report initially loads fine with the dataset as the datasource why would I need credentials when trying to page through the rest of the report? Is there a way to disable this?

My code for creating the datatset and setting the datasource is below. *(search_criteria, customers, expenses_dt are my datatables with the relevant information for the report.)*

```
            DataSet ds = new expenseReportDataSet();

            ds.Tables["search_criteria"].Merge(search_criteria);
            ds.Tables["Customer"].Merge(customers);
            ds.Tables["expense"].Merge(expenses_dt);


            ReportDocument expenses = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("exp_report_by_consult.rpt");
            expenses.Load(reportPath);

            expenses.SetDataSource(ds);

            cr_view_expenses.ReportSource = expenses;
```

Comment: How is your database defined in Database Expert within the Crystal Report?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow (I'm still rather new to Crystal Reports). If it helps, the selected tables for the report in the database expert are from my ADO.NET dataset, expenseReportDataset. I created the dataset within the project itself and not the database.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution to the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260014/logon-failed-error-when-navigating-to-next-page-on-crystal-reports-vs2008/33262971#33262971). It turns out that I was losing the report document on postback. Storing the report document in a session then resetting the report source of the CrystalReportViewer after postback did the trick. Thanks for the help though.